# Need help to pass correct array to subrutine in perl a better (prettier) way

Tags: perl, arrays

Have scraped some data from web. I got data in a structure $res that looks something like this  (see below - using datadumper). $res is an array of hashes, with a hash array pageurls

Want to get lastpage from pageurls, this is always in the last array of pageurls.
sub lastpage has two arguments page (current page) ang the array pageurls.

```
$res = {
       'pageurls' => [
                       bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://digitalarkivet.arkivverket.no/finn_kilde?s=&fra=&til=&ka%5B0%5D=1&kt%5B0%5D=MANN&kt%5B1%5D=MINI&kt%5B2%5D=KLOK&kt%5B3%5D=FREG&k%5B0%5D=1820&k%5B1%5D=1843&k%5B2%5D=1804&page=1')}, 'URI::http' ),
                       bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://digitalarkivet.arkivverket.no/finn_kilde?s=&fra=&til=&ka%5B0%5D=1&kt%5B0%5D=MANN&kt%5B1%5D=MINI&kt%5B2%5D=KLOK&kt%5B3%5D=FREG&k%5B0%5D=1820&k%5B1%5D=1843&k%5B2%5D=1804&page=2')}, 'URI::http' )
                     ],
       'page' => '1',
       'comment' => " S\x{f8}ket ditt gav 74 treff: "
       }

my $lastpage = &lastPage($res->{'page'},$res->{'pageurls'});

sub lastPage {
    my @pageurls=$_[1];

    if (@pageurls) {
        my @bits= split /page=/,$pageurls[0][-1];
        my $rv=$bits[-1];

        return $rv
    } else {
        return $_[0];
    }
}

#Looking in debugger I see the following structure for @pageurls
#[0]
#  ->[0] http....
#  ->[1] http....
```

How do I pass pageurls as a one dimensional array, and use it afterwards?

Comment: I am always sympathetic with people who struggle to ask a question in English, but some of what you have written is perfect, including punctuation. That leads me to guess that the language in your question is poor because of indolence, which never goes down too well when you are asking for help for free.

Comment: First I thought I'd not bother commenting this. You're entitled to your own opinion, never less there were no laziness on my behalf. I actually spent several hours on variations of code back and forth trying to solve this, trying to pass with and without dereference it. But I didn't do it right. And FYI, I struggle even with my Norwegian writing. I often don't see my misspelling (on screen). I didn't spell check it anyway, sorry my bad. Next time don't assume stuff @Borodin. Hope this was better English I've tried to write properly (again). Like last time I've put effort behind this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
my @pageurls=$_[1];
```

`$_[1]` is an array reference, so you have to dereference it to get an array.

```
my @pageurls = @{ $_[1] };
```

Then, you can just use `$pageurls[-1]` to acces the last one.

If you want to pass pageurls as a list, you can dereference it in the call:

```
my $lastpage = lastPage($res->{page}, @{ $res->{pageurls} });
```

You then have to change the processing of the arguments of the subroutine:

```
sub lastPage {
    my $page = shift;  # Remove the first member from @_.
    my @pageurls = @_;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, and made it easy to understand